# Local server hosting mySQL on Mac, what's the database URL?

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache

For experimentations purposes, I am hosting a local Apache server connected to a mySQL database on my Mac (following this really good tutorial: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-macos-sierra/)

Now, I need to connect this database to a client application. This application asks me for the "server URL". I access the server from my browser with this address: http://localhost/~username, but what the client app is asking me is a different thing. What is this URL, and how can I find it when the database in stored locally?

Comment: What is the client application? You don't typically connect to a "URL" with a MySQL client, you'd connect to a host and port.

Comment: The local host name is "localhost" and the MySQL port is 3306. MySQL isn't typically connected to by URL.

Comment: Thanks! My problem is that the client application is an academic app built specifically for my lab by somebody who doesn't work here anymore. So my problem is not reproducible (hence the downvotes?)... I'll try further with your info and hopefully clarify the question to make it useful. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Basically you wanted to get connected with your local mysql, right? If you are looking for this answer then follow the below.

After Configuring apache you need to follow these steps to get connect with local MySQL.

1. Download the "Mac OS X 10.12 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive" - **dmg version** from **https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.7.html** and install the mysql in your mac machine. At end of the installation root password will be generated. kindly copy that password into notes or other files
2. In terminal follow these steps (PURE OPTIONAL)

   - "**cd /usr/local/mysql/bin**" click enter button
   - "**sudo ./mysql -u root -p**" click enter and terminal will ask for 
     password and you need to copy paste the MySQL ROOT password which i 
     mentioned the step 1 and enter.
   - now you will be into mysql and if you want to change the ROOT 
     password then enter this command in terminal "**Alter user 
     'root'@'localhost' identified by 'your new password which you like 
     to change';**" enter and exit from terminal
3. Download phpmyadmin from https://www.phpmyadmin.net/ and extract the phpmyadmin file and rename it as **phpMyAdmin**into your WebServer/Documents folder **( /Library/WebServer/Documents/)**
4. Go to Terminal and enter the following command

   - **cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/** and click enter
   - **cd phpMyAdmin** and click enter
   - **sudo mkdir config** and click enter
   - **sudo chmod o+x config** and click enter
5. Go to Browser URL and enter the following **localhost/phpmyadmin/setup** and server set up page will be open and follow the below steps

   - Click on **New Server** button then navigate to authentication tab 
     and enter the **ROOT PASSWORD** & click apply button
   - At bottom of overview page you can find Download button and click 
     that and **config.inc.php** file will be downloaded
   - copy paste the **config.inc.php** file inside your **phpMyAdmin** 
     folder
6. Go to your browser url then enter **localhost/phpmyadmin/** and enter with your credentials into database

this is your local database location which is stored locally in your machine